# Allowed Keyboard Shortcuts for Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When you creating a Chrome browser extension, you may suggest keyboard shortcuts by implementing the [chrome.commands](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) API.  Is there a documented list of allowed key combinations?  Chrome seems to reject virtually every combination I offer despite the fact that I know they are not used by any of the systems I'm targeting.

I'm aware of the keyboard shortcuts listed [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en&ref_topic=25799), but shortcuts not appearing on this list still do not work.

Comment: Just skimming through the document you linked, do `Ctrl+Shift+5`, `Ctrl+Shift+Y`, or `Alt+Shift+P` work? Those are some of the examples listed.

Comment: Also, you might want to check `chrome://extensions/configureCommands` to see if your keys are assigned to your commands.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation is [quite precise](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands#usage) in that respect. I will quote the documentation, but be aware it's subject to change. This answer is based on documentation as of 2015-02-09

> Supported keys: A-Z, 0-9, Comma, Period, Home, End, PageUp, PageDown, Space, Insert, Delete, Arrow keys (Up, Down, Left, Right) and the Media Keys (MediaNextTrack, MediaPlayPause, MediaPrevTrack, MediaStop).
>
> Note: All key combinations must include either Ctrl* or Alt. Combinations that involve Ctrl+Alt are not permitted in order to avoid conflicts with the AltGr key. Shift can be used in addition to Alt or Ctrl, but is not required. Modifiers (such as Ctrl) can not be used in combination with the Media Keys. Tab key was removed from list of supported keys in Chrome version 33 and above for accessibility reasons.
>
> - Also note that on Mac 'Ctrl' is automatically converted to 'Command'. If you want 'Ctrl' instead, please specify 'MacCtrl'.

So, a combination MUST contain <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> but **not both**, optionally contain <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then one of the "supported keys".

Additionally,

> Certain Chrome shortcuts (e.g. window management) always take priority over Extension Command shortcuts and can not be overwritten.

This covers commands that Chrome listens to while focused. For system-level commands, it is restricted to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>
+<kbd>(number)</kbd>

There are additional rules specifically for Chrome OS, read the same documentation for those.

---

Also, note that changing suggested keys for an already-installed extension may not trigger their assignment. Try to reinstall the extension instead of reloading it when testing.

Finally, as Whymarrh suggested, you can see the keybindings at `chrome://extensions/shortcuts`