# Chrome extension keydown listener in background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating an extension that will allow users to use chrome-like tab switching on Vivaldi browser.

In my background.js I have tried

```
addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    console.log(e.code); // never gets here
})
```

I originally had the event being handled by a content.js script, however this required any new tabs to be completely loaded before I could send messages to the background.js script

```
function Listener()
{
    this.stage = 0;
    this.listen();
}

Listener.prototype.listen = function()
{
    addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyDown);
    addEventListener("keyup", this.handleKeyUp);
}

Listener.prototype.handleKeyDown = function(event)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if(event.ctrlKey) {
            if(event.code == "Digit" + (i + 1)) {
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                    greeting: i
                }, function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
new Listener();
```

I want to move this functionality to my background.js so that it runs independently of browser actions.

Comment: Only content script has access to DOM related even happening on current web page, what do you mean "this required any new tabs to be completely loaded before I could send messages to the background.js script“ ? When do you want your script to be executed?

Comment: I want my script to be executed regardless of what tabs are loaded @HaibaraAi - it's a tab switcher, so if I open a new tab I want to be able to use a key combination to switch back to tab one with, for example ctrl + 1, which I can do but I simply have to wait for the new tab to load first.

Comment: then I believe @Xan is right, `chrome.commands` is for that purpose, though many limitation like all key combinations must include Ctrl or Alt, ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DOM keyboard event listeners capture only keystrokes that happen when the focus is within the page.

A background page cannot be shown, and as such, cannot be focused. It will never receive any input events.

You may want to look into [`chrome.commands` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands), but it is fairly restrictive. For a good reason: you *really, really* don't want extensions to be able to just harvest all keystrokes.

You could partially bypass the restrictions by using a (valid) command to *invoke* your extension, which would open its popup, which in turn can capture further events with DOM listeners.

Comment: I understand this - however, relying on the DOM events requires the new tab to be loaded before I can switch back to another tab;

For example: You open a new tab (ctrl + t) - the content.js script kicks in and starts listening for requests when you load a web-page, but in that time ctrl + 1/2/3/4.. won't be picked up by the listener to switch to those respective tabs. @Xan

Comment: That's because the whole "trying to collect keystrokes by content scripts" is a hack when semantically you want them to work anywhere in the browser. It won't work reliably, period. You do have a tool - `chrome.commands` - for browser-wide shortcuts but it has limitations you'll have to live with.

Comment: Note that I have a detailed answer on what kind of shortcuts are allowed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28410213/934239 For instance, you can't override Chrome's existing shortcuts.